# Panels content wrapper

Tags: views, panels, theming

I realised that this was a horribly verbose question, so decided to edit it and try again!

I am trying to find a way of wrapping a set of three (or more) Panels content areas with a div - is that possible?

[image]

Comment: I question the usefulness of this. Why would you not add a region instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Panels Extra Styles](http://drupal.org/project/panels_extra_styles) module. You can wrap panes or panes in HTML

Comment: I havent tried it yet, but it looks to be exactly what I needed, thanks!

Comment: the panels extra styles doesnt work to wrap panes.

Answer (score 6):

You can definitely use the Panels Extra Styles module to wrap multiple panes in as many tags as you need.

On the first pane of your new group click the option cog and, under the Style section (which should read No style), choose 'Change'. Change the selected style to Wrapper:Raw and enter your opening tags in the text area 'Content prefix'. Leave the suffix area blank (as you don't want to close any tags yet)

Save the changes and then do the same with the last pane you want to group. This time close all the tags opened in the first pane by entering them in the 'Content suffix' text area.

Save and update your panel page and et voila! Your panes are grouped with your own HTML!

Comment: I just tried this and it works great, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

There is a way without additional modules using custom Panels content.

- Add a custom content pane where you want to start the wrapper, add the opening tag as body, make sure to not use WYSIWYG Editors which may add additional markup and don't add a title.
- Set style to: *No markup at all*
- Add another custom content pane analogous to the first one where you want to end the wrapper with the closing tag.

Thath's it, after saving the panel content you will see the grouping produced by the wrapper, as shown in the attached screenshot.

[image]