# Add a wrapper around two panes

Tags: panels

[image]

I want to add a wrapper around the panes which are shown in red box in the given image. How to achieve it.

I have already tried [Panels Extra Styles](https://drupal.org/project/panels_extra_styles) module but it is not providing a wrapper around two or more panes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Panels content wrapper](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/52045/panels-content-wrapper) If you're not happy with the previous answer then you need to explain why yours is different. And: "Didn't work" is not enough.

Comment: The panel extra styles is making one pane id div as child div of other pane id but it is not wrapping the both panes.I want a parent div wrapping two panes.

Answer (score 1):

Create mini Panel, and add that. In mini panel you give classes, so you can wrap a class.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [panels extra styles module](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels_extra_styles), and [fences module](https://www.drupal.org/project/fences), here is an image explaining how to do it. [wrapper div image](https://www.drupal.org/files/images/fences-screenshot.png), both modules are avilable for D7 and D8

Comment: That didn't explain it at all FYI

Comment: Complete Answer: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/81963/10316

Comment: See also my answer without using additional modules: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/261082/10316